# setState does not update the widgets created from data returned from an async call

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, widget, setstate

I am getting data from firebase in the initState and when the data is retrieved the widgets are updated as expected.
I get a list of DocumentSnapshots and from those i construct a list of rows containing RaisedButtons, i want to disable a single raised button after it has been clicked, but I can't get it to work.
I am just a beginner, help will be appreciated !

This is my stateful widget

```
class _UpdateSemesterState extends State<UpdateSemester> {
  final _cloud = Firestore.instance;
  final dbHandler = FirebaseCaller();
  
  // the widget displayed
  Widget batchWidget;

  Map<String, String> currentSemesters;
  
  // this map holds the booleans that should define which buttons have been clicked
  Map<String, bool> _updating;
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentSemesters = Map<String, String>();
    _updating = Map<String, bool>();
    Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> batches = dbHandler.getActiveBatches();
    

    // after getting values from firebase, call this method to set the state
    batches.then((value) {
      if (value.isNotEmpty) {
        batchWidget = ListView(
          children: value.map((item) {

            currentSemesters[item.documentID] = item.data['current semester'];
            
            // set the boolean for this row
            _updating[item.documentID] = false;
            
             return Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Text(
                    "Batch ${item.documentID}",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    decoration: kBatchYearTextFieldDecor,
                    items: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
                        .map(
                          (e) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: e,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                e,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                    value: currentSemesters[item.documentID],
                    hint: Text("Semester not set"),
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        currentSemesters[item.documentID] = value;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),

                // this is the button i want to disable after clicking
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: _updating[item.documentID]
                          ? null
                          : () {
                                print(_updating[item.documentID]);
                                setState(() {
                                  _updating[item.documentID] = true;
                                });
                                print(_updating[item.documentID]);
                                Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _updating[item.documentID] = false;
                                  });
                                });
                                return null;
                              },
                      child: _updating[item.documentID]
                          ? Container(
                              width: 15.0,
                              height: 15.0,
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                strokeWidth: 1.0,
                              ),
                            )
                          : Text("Update"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      } else {
        batchWidget = Center(child: Text("No Active Batches"));
      }
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build called");
    print(_updating);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Update Batch Semester"),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: _isLoading
                  ? Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator():batchWidget,
            ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have a `Future` use `FutureBuilder` inside your `build()` method - please dont make simple things complex

Comment: @pskink I tried FutureBuilder as well, and i also tried StreamBuilder, the problem is with the logic of the button i guess

Comment: so follow the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) official docs - they have some sample code

Comment: @pskink i cant get it to work, can u help me out here please

Answer (score 0):

It was because everytime the build was called by setState the value of the variable that was button was depending upon was getting reset to the value I had gotten from the async call.
So basically changing the statement

```
_updating[item.documentID] = false;
```

to

```
_updating[item.documentID] = _updating[item.documentID] ?? false;
```

which checks if the boolean variable is null
and if it null, then there is no problem setting it to the value returned from async call, but if it is set, then there is no need to set it to the value returned from async call.